# Not able to connect to custom NiFi port

Tags: apache-nifi

I have configured the port to 9090 in the properties of the conf file. Following are the only 2 changes I have made:

- nifi.web.http.host=localhost
- nifi.web.http.port=9090

When I run the file and go to the link I get the 'local host refused to connect' error
Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

@Omkar Ingate

I have multiple nifis in a dev environment including one that I have on 9090.  The only change i make is to the port.  I do not touch host, so config looks like:

```
nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=9090
```

I recommend avoiding "localhost".  Let nifi attach to the correct host by default, which is actually going to be some form of your environments external and local ip addresses, and not "localhost".   The server logs report as follows:

```
NiFi has started. The UI is available at the following URLs:
http://192.168.74.101:9090/nifi
http://10.0.2.15:9090/nifi
http://172.17.0.1:9090/nifi
http://127.0.0.1:9090/nifi
```